# Bash script / utility to convert UK English to US spellings in TeX document

Tags: bash, awk, sed, latex, spelling

I'm looking for a quick Bash script to convert British / New Zealand spellings to American in a TeX document (for working with US-based academics and journal submission). This is a formal mathematical biology paper with very little regional terminology or grammar: prior work is given as formulae rather than quotes.

e.g.,

`Generalise` -> `Generalize`

`Colour` -> `Color`

`Centre` -> `Centre`

Figure there must be `sed` or `awk` based script to substitute most of the common spelling differences.

See the related TeX forum question for more detail.

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/312138/converting-uk-to-us-spellings

n.b. I currently compile PDFLaTeX with `kile` on Ubuntu 16.04 or Elementary OS 0.3 Freya but I can use another TeX compiler/package if there's a built-in fix elsewhere.

Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: "Replace" does not do the job for you?

Comment: The script is trivial. The data, however... Can you provide a suitable list of substitutions?

Comment: Well, I could use `sed` or `awk` to replace each case separately. I was hoping someone had already prepared a loop or script for common cases. Indeed sourcing a list of common substitutions is another challenge. If were to do it myself, I'd set it up on github to update when encountering new cases.

Comment: Hi Tom, You can change the sed line in RandomUser's solution to : 

`sed -i "s/\([^\\]\)$word/\1$updatedWord/g" $sourceFile 2 > /dev/null` 

The words that begins "\" (LaTeX commands) will be prevented from substitution in this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to have a list of substitution handy with you and call it for translation.  You would have to enrich your dictionary file to efficiently translate text files.

```
sourceFile=$1
dict=$2

while read line
    do
     word=$(echo $line |awk '{print $1}')
     updatedWord=$(grep -i $word $dict|awk '{print $2}')

     sed -i "s/$word/$updatedWord/g" $sourceFile 2 > /dev/null

   done < $dict
```

Run the above script like:

```
./scriptName source.txt dictionary.txt
```

Here is one sample dictionary I used:

```
>cat dict
characterize characterise
prioritize prioritise
specialize specialise
analyze analyse
catalyze catalyse
size size
exercise exercise
behavior behaviour
color colour
favor favour
contour contour
center centre
fiber fibre
liter litre
parameter parameter
ameba amoeba
anesthesia anaesthesia
diarrhea diarrhoea
esophagus oesophagus
leukemia leukaemia
cesium caesium
defense defence
practice  practice
license  licence
defensive defensive
advice  advice
aging ageing
acknowledgment acknowledgement
judgment judgement
analog analogue
dialog dialogue
fulfill fulfil
enroll enrol
skill, skillful skill, skilful
labeled labelled
signaling signalling
propelled propelled
revealing revealing
```

Execution result :

```
cat source
color of this fiber is great and we should analyze it.

./ScriptName source.txt dict.txt

cat source
colour of this fibre is great and we should analyse it.
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I had in mind very helpful. That dictionary is a great starting point to add use cases as they come up in a file or on the web. Is there a way to exclude words if they're used for code e.g., `\color` `xcolor` `color{` so switching wouldn't mess up the LaTeX tags? Typically I write in UK spelling and need to preserve US spelling for code or latex. Thinking this would be beneficial if I (or anyone else) in the future, need to switch US to UK spelling.

Comment: Using a shell `while read` to perform a text transformation on every line of input is an antipattern.  You should probably be looking at Awk for this instead.  (A number of other scripting languages would do fine as well.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution with `awk` that I think is more flexible than `sed`.
This prg. leaves the LaTeX commands (when word begins with "\") and it will preserve the first capital letters of words.
The parameters of LaTeX commands (and normal texts) will be substitute by dictionary file.
When [rev] the third parameter of program is on it will do a revers substitution by same dictionary file.
Any non alpha-beta character functions as word separator (this is required in LaTeX source file).
The prg writes its output on the screen (stdout) so you need to use the redirection to file ( >output_f).
(I think inputencoding of your LaTeX source is 1 byte/char.)

```
> cat dic.sh
#!/bin/bash
(($#<2))&& { echo "Usage $0 dictionary_file latex_file [rev]"; exit 1; }
((d= $#==3 ? 0:1))
awk -v d=$d '
 BEGIN {cm=fx=0; fn="";}
 fn!=FILENAME {fx++; fn=FILENAME;}
 fx==1 {if(!NF)next; if(d)a[$1]=$2; else a[$2]=$1; next;} #read dict or rev dict file into an associative array
 fx==2 { for(i=1; i<=length($0); i++)
            {c=substr($0,i,1);                            #read characters from a given line of LaTeX source    
             if(cm){printf("%s",c); if(c~"[^A-Za-z0-9\\\]")cm=0;}  #LaTeX command is occurred
             else if(c~"[A-Za-z]")w=w c; else{pr(); printf("%s",c); if(c=="\\")cm=1;} #collect alpha-bets or handle them
            }
         pr(); printf("\n");                              #handle collected last word in the line 
       }
function pr(  s){   # print collected word or its substitution by dictionary and recreates first letter case
   if(!length(w))return;
   s=tolower(w);
   if(!(s in a))printf("%s",w);
   else printf("%s", s==w ? a[s] : toupper(substr(a[s],1,1)) substr(a[s],2));
   w="";}
' $1 $2
```

Dictionary file:

```
> cat dictionary
apple      lemon
raspberry  cherry
pear       banana
```

Input LaTeX source:

```
> cat src.txt
Apple123pear,apple "pear".
\Apple123pear{raspberry}{pear}[apple].

Raspberry12Apple,pear.
```

Execution result :

```
> ./dic.sh 
Usage ./dic.sh dictionary_file latex_file [rev]

> ./dic.sh dictionary src.txt >out1.txt; cat out1.txt
Lemon123banana,lemon "banana".
\Apple123pear{cherry}{banana}[lemon].

Cherry12Lemon,banana.

> ./dic.sh dictionary out1.txt >out2.txt rev; cat out2.txt
Apple123pear,apple "pear".
\Apple123pear{raspberry}{pear}[apple].

Raspberry12Apple,pear.

> diff src.txt out2.txt   # they are identical
```